# i need to send data from an html from with a paypal payment how can this be done

Tags: php, html, paypal

I am a little lost.  I want to registrant sign up for a race and pay at the same time using paypal.  what is the best way to go about this?  I haven't started coding the paypal part yet, as i haven't figured out where to start.

Comment: In your paypal account, go to `Merchant Service` tab, all the instructions and information you need should be there.

Comment: Another option is [Stripe](http://stripe.com/)

Comment: One small problem I don't have access to the paypal account, it isn't my account.  so is there a way around going into merchant services?

Answer (score 0):

Make a multi part form.. first insert the details in the database, then on the final page get the values back and send them to paypal.